# Derivation of Divergence with Wedge-Shaped Surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Synopsis**

We are given the following exercise from *Div Grad Curl and All That*:

[image: From Div Grad Curl and All That]

I'm having a little bit of trouble with the rectangular shaped sides (you'll see what I mean when you look at my attempt), and I was wondering if I could have a hint or a little bit of help.

**My Attempt**

Our approach will be to derive $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$ using the definition $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} \equiv \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V} \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}\ dS.$$ So we will calculate the flux per unit volume of some $\mathbf{F}$ through the wedge-shaped surface (by looking at each of the 5 sides) and take the limit as $\Delta V$ approaches 0.

Let $(x,y,z)$ be the lower left point of the wedge most in the $x$-direction. First, we consider the triangular sides with normal vectors $\mathbf{\hat{i}}$ and $-\mathbf{\hat{i}}$. Assuming the wedge is small, we have $$\iint_{S_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \iint_{S_1} F_x(x,y,z)\ dS \approx F_x\left(x,y+\frac{\Delta y}{2}, z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)\left( \frac{\Delta z \Delta y}{2}\right)$$ for the triangle facing most towards us, and $$\iint_{S_2} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = -\iint_{S_2} F_x(x,y,z)\ dS \approx -F_x\left(x-\Delta x,y+\frac{\Delta y}{2}, z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)\left( \frac{\Delta z \Delta y}{2}\right)$$ for the triangle in the back (the negative comes from the unit vector pointing in the opposite direction).

Hence, we have $$\iint_{S_1+S_2} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \frac{F_x\left(x,y+\frac{\Delta y}{2}, z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)-F_x\left(x-\Delta x,y+\frac{\Delta y}{2}, z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)}{\Delta x}\left(\frac{\Delta x \Delta y \Delta z}{2}\right).$$ Recognizing that $\Delta V = (\Delta x \Delta y \Delta z)/2$, we have that $$\frac{1}{\Delta V} \iint_{S_1+S_2} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \frac{F_x\left(x,y+\frac{\Delta y}{2}, z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)-F_x\left(x-\Delta x,y+\frac{\Delta y}{2}, z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)}{\Delta x}.$$ Noting that as $\Delta V \to 0$, we have $\Delta x \to 0$, we therefore have $$\lim_{\Delta V \to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta V} \iint_{S_1+S_2} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{F_x\left(x,y+\frac{\Delta y}{2}, z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)-F_x\left(x-\Delta x,y+\frac{\Delta y}{2}, z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)}{\Delta x} = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}.$$

Now we come to the rectangular shaped sides. From the exercise, we know that deriving the flux per unit volume of these 3 sides as the volume approaches 0 should yield $$\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}.$$ The only question is how. I will attempt here now, but as you can see, I'm a bit stuck.

Consider the rectangular side parallel to the $xz$-plane. Call this surface $S_3$. Here, the unit normal vector is $-\mathbf{\hat{j}}$, so $$ \iint_{S_3} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = -\iint_{S_3} F_y(x,y,z)\ dS \approx -F_y\left( x- \frac{\Delta x}{2},y,z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right)\left(\Delta z \Delta x\right).$$ Similarly, for the rectangular side parallel to the $xy$-plane ($S_4$), we have $-\mathbf{\hat{k}}$ as the unit normal vector and $$ \iint_{S_4} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = -\iint_{S_4} F_z(x,y,z)\ dS \approx -F_z\left( x- \frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z \right)\left(\Delta y \Delta x\right).$$ The difficult part comes with the last rectangular side of the wedge ($S_5$). First, we look for the coordinates of the center of the rectangle. We note that the rectangle is made of the points $(x,y+\Delta y,z), (x,y,z+\Delta z), (x-\Delta x, y, z+\Delta z),$ and $(x-\Delta x, y+\Delta y, z)$. Finding the centroid, we have the coordinates to be $\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right)$ (I thought intuitively that this would be it, but I wasn't sure, so I went with the longer method of averaging the coordinates of the four points). Furthermore, we have the unit normal vector to be $\mathbf{\hat{n}} = \frac{\mathbf{\hat{j}}+\mathbf{\hat{k}}}{\sqrt{2}}$ (I think). Taking the surface integral, we then have $$ \iint_{S_5} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \iint_{S_5} F_y(x,y,z) + F_z(x,y,z) \ dS \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( F_y\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right)+ F_z\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right)\right)\left(\Delta x\sqrt{(\Delta z)^2+(\Delta y)^2}\right).$$ But here is where I am confused. It seems *so* close (if we look at the $F_y$ and $F_z$ terms in our formulas they seem so close to coming near the definition of the derivative), but the $\sqrt{2}$ term and especially the $\Delta x\sqrt{(\Delta z)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$ term are throwing me off. Any suggestions?

---

Wait wait wait! I've answered my own question! My unit normal vector was wrong. Indeed, $\mathbf{\hat{n}} = \frac{\Delta z \ \mathbf{\hat{j}} + \Delta y \ \mathbf{\hat{k}}}{\sqrt{(\Delta z)^2+(\Delta y)^2}}$. My original normal vector assumed $\Delta y = \Delta z$. So we have $$\iint_{\sum_3^5 S_n} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \Delta x \left( \Delta z \left(F_y\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right) - F_y\left(x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y,z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)\right) + \Delta y \left( F_z\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right) - F_z\left( x- \frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z \right) \right)\right).$$ Dividing this cumbersome expression by $\Delta V = (\Delta x \Delta y \Delta z)/2$ and letting $\Delta V \to 0$ (and with it, $\Delta y, \Delta z \to 0$) we get $$\lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V}\iint_{\sum_3^5 S_n} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \lim_{\Delta y,\Delta z \to 0} \left(\frac{2}{\Delta y \Delta z} \left( \Delta z \left(F_y\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right) - F_y\left(x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y,z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)\right) + \Delta y \left( F_z\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right) - F_z\left( x- \frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z \right) \right)\right) \right)= \lim_{\Delta y,\Delta z \to 0} \left(\frac{2 \left(F_y\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right) - F_y\left(x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y,z+\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right)\right) }{\Delta y} + \frac{2 \left(F_z\left( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z+\frac{\Delta z}{2} \right) - F_z\left( x- \frac{\Delta x}{2},y+\frac{\Delta y}{2},z \right)\right)}{\Delta z}\right) = \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}.$$ Therefore, we have $$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V}\iint_{\sum_1^5 S_n} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}!$$